# jquery remote validation - async?

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain the difference between setting `async = true` and `async = false` in the snippet below? I understand the concept of `asynchronous` (validating in the background) but don't understand what the implications are in form validation.

```
'data[orderPrefix]': {
                required: true,
                alphanum: true,
                remote: {
                    url: site_url+"shops/validate",
                    async: true,
                    data: {
                        task: function() {
                            return $("#task").val();
                        },
                        shopID: function() {
                            return $("#shopID").val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

I had a form where multiple fields have js validation (both standard and remote) and certain rules simply didn't catch invalid data. After changing async from false to true, everything works fine.

The jquery docs don't really explain much regarding this and I want to understand why my changes "work".

EDIT: I'm using 1.9 of the bassistance.de plugin with jquery 1.7.2.

Comment: it would help if you said what plugin you use for the validation and paste some code of the parts that were not validated (as well as those that were validated)... right now, I wouldn't be able to help you with the information provided so far

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is general question about asynchronous programming, not about validation. So maybe you want to read up about it:

http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs168/f12/handouts/async.pdf
http://www.slideshare.net/clutchski/writing-asynchronous-javascript-101
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135762/learning-asynchronous-programming

Though for those of you who are interested in asynchronous validations, checkout: http://verifyjs.com